# ToPascalCase() C# for all caps Abbreviations

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0, pascalcasing

I am using ReSharper and trying to abide by it's default rules.

In part of my code, I need to change a string Property to PascalCase.

I have tried numerous methods but cannot find one that works for things which include all capital Abbreviations.

EX:

```
MPSUser --> Still MPSUser (should be MpsUser)
ArticleID --> Still Article ID (Should be ArticleId)
closeMethod --> Works and changes to CloseMethod
```

Can anyone help me create a method that can turn any String to PascalCase?
Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can register abbreviations with ReSharper and it will allow them to be used in PascalCased names. For example, for ArticleID you would register ID as an abbreviation, and it would no longer complain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only built-in method I know of for converting to `PascalCase` is [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX), and it doesn't handle all-caps words by design.  To work around this, I have crafted a custom regular expression that can detect all the word parts, and then they are individually converted to Title/Pascal Case:

```
string ToPascalCase(string s)
{
    // Find word parts using the following rules:
    // 1. all lowercase starting at the beginning is a word
    // 2. all caps is a word.
    // 3. first letter caps, followed by all lowercase is a word
    // 4. the entire string must decompose into words according to 1,2,3.
    // Note that 2&3 together ensure MPSUser is parsed as "MPS" + "User".

    var m = Regex.Match(s, "^(?<word>^[a-z]+|[A-Z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+)+$");
    var g = m.Groups["word"];

    // Take each word and convert individually to TitleCase
    // to generate the final output.  Note the use of ToLower
    // before ToTitleCase because all caps is treated as an abbreviation.
    var t = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in g.Captures.Cast<Capture>())
        sb.Append(t.ToTitleCase(c.Value.ToLower()));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This function should handle the common use cases:

```
s           | ToPascalCase(s)
MPSUser     | MpsUser
ArticleID   | ArticleId
closeMethod | CloseMethod
```

Answer (score 3):

I borrowed heavily from mellamokb's solution to come up with something a little more comprehensive.  For example, I wanted to leave numbers alone.  Also, I wanted any non-letter, non-number character to be used as a delimiter.  Here it is:

```
    public static string ToPascalCase(this string s) {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        var nonWordChars = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        var tokens = nonWordChars.Split(s);
        foreach (var token in tokens) {
            result.Append(PascalCaseSingleWord(token));
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }

    static string PascalCaseSingleWord(string s) {
        var match = Regex.Match(s, @"^(?<word>\d+|^[a-z]+|[A-Z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+|\d[a-z]+)+$");
        var groups = match.Groups["word"];

        var textInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var capture in groups.Captures.Cast<Capture>()) {
            result.Append(textInfo.ToTitleCase(capture.Value.ToLower()));
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Here is an x-unit test that shows some test cases:

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("imAString", "ImAString")]
    [InlineData("imAlsoString", "ImAlsoString")]
    [InlineData("ImAlsoString", "ImAlsoString")]
    [InlineData("im_a_string", "ImAString")]
    [InlineData("im a string", "ImAString")]
    [InlineData("ABCAcronym", "AbcAcronym")]
    [InlineData("im_a_ABCAcronym", "ImAAbcAcronym")]
    [InlineData("im a ABCAcronym", "ImAAbcAcronym")]
    [InlineData("8ball", "8Ball")]
    [InlineData("im a 8ball", "ImA8Ball")]
    [InlineData("IM_ALL_CAPS", "ImAllCaps")]
    [InlineData("IM ALSO ALL CAPS", "ImAlsoAllCaps")]
    [InlineData("i-have-dashes", "IHaveDashes")]
    [InlineData("a8word_another_word", "A8WordAnotherWord")]
    public void WhenGivenString_ShouldPascalCaseIt(string input, string expectedResult) {
        var result = input.ToPascalCase();
        Assert.Equal(expectedResult, result);
    }
```